# pandas dataframe getting daily/weekly/hourly data

Tags: datetime, pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have a pandas dataframe with index = datetime.datetime(year,month,day,hour,minute)

I want to be able to use this to get hourly/ daily /weekly data where hourly data would be the last entry corresponding to every hour in the frame.

Is there any inbuilt way to do this? I tried making cases e.g. in case of daily data, i changed the hour and minute entry to zero, but I still have a dataframe with multiple entries for the same day. How can I get the last entry corresponding to each day?

sample dataframe:

```
         index                x          y
2016-01-01 00:07:00-05:00   1.000      0.000
2016-01-01 00:10:00-05:00   1.000      0.000
2016-01-01 00:15:00-05:00   1.000      0.000
2016-01-01 00:16:00-05:00   1.000      0.000
2016-01-01 00:20:00-05:00   1.000      0.000
2016-01-01 00:21:00-05:00   1.000      0.000
2016-01-01 00:26:00-05:00   1.000      0.000
2016-01-01 00:31:00-05:00   1.000      0.000
2016-01-01 00:37:00-05:00   1.000      0.000
2016-01-01 00:40:00-05:00   1.000      0.000
2016-01-01 00:46:00-05:00   1.000      0.000
2016-01-01 00:51:00-05:00   1.000      0.000
2016-01-01 00:56:00-05:00   1.000      0.000
2016-01-03 19:26:00-05:00   1.000      0.000
2016-01-03 19:34:00-05:00   1.000      0.000
2016-01-03 20:02:00-05:00   1.000      0.000
2016-01-03 20:06:00-05:00   1.000      0.000
2016-01-03 20:07:00-05:00   1.000      0.000
2016-01-03 20:08:00-05:00   1.000      0.000
2016-01-03 20:10:00-05:00   1.000      0.000
2016-01-03 20:11:00-05:00   1.000      0.000
2016-01-03 20:12:00-05:00   1.000      0.000
2016-01-03 20:13:00-05:00   1.000      0.000
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming I understand your question (it would be helpful to see some code for examples), it sounds like you could use resample:

```
df.resample('D', how='sum')
```

It works like a groupby or pivot table:

> DataFrame.resample(rule, how=None, axis=0, fill_method=None,
>   closed=None, label=None, convention='start', kind=None, loffset=None,
>   limit=None, base=0) Convenience method for frequency conversion and
>   resampling of regular time-series data.
>
> Parameters:    rule : string the offset string or object representing
>   target conversion axis : int, optional, default 0 closed : {‘right’,
>   ‘left’} Which side of bin interval is closed label : {‘right’, ‘left’}
>   Which bin edge label to label bucket with convention : {‘start’,
>   ‘end’, ‘s’, ‘e’} loffset : timedelta Adjust the resampled time labels
>   base : int, default 0 For frequencies that evenly subdivide 1 day, the
>   “origin” of the aggregated intervals. For example, for ‘5min’
>   frequency, base could range from 0 through 4. Defaults to 0

Comment: If you are doing the resampling in version 1.4, then you need to do this: `df.resample('D').sum()`